# unable to access server in docker container from outside host machine

Tags: docker, containers, docker-network

I have a linux machine (Host-591) hosting 2 VM instances. In the first VM instance (Docker03), inside a container, I have a Flask web server hosted, which runs on tcp/81 and publishes it. The host machine, Docker03 maps it to port tcp/5003. 
From Docker03, I am able to access the Flask server:

```
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# curl http://192.168.122.103:5003/
Hello Root!
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3#
```

But from the host linux machine, I am not able to access the server.

```
[root@Host-591 ~]# curl http://192.168.122.103:5003/
^C
```

Ping from the host machine to the server in the container inside Docker03 works fine.

```
[root@Host-591 ~]# ping 192.168.122.103 -c 1
PING 192.168.122.103 (192.168.122.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.122.103: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.225 ms

--- 192.168.122.103 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.225/0.225/0.225/0.000 ms
```

A simple telnet from the Host machine to the Flask server's port shows TCP connection can be established:

```
[root@Host-591 ~]# telnet 192.168.122.103 5003
Trying 192.168.122.103...
Connected to 192.168.122.103.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.


[root@Host-591 ~]# ifconfig virbr0
virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:1a:d4:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30436  bytes 7466531 (7.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 24  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42414  bytes 65991140 (62.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The iptables rules on Docker03 VM instance looks like:

```
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# iptables -t nat -vL -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 84 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    84 DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    3   204 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 84 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 364 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   240 DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 364 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   240 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match src-type LOCAL
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker_gwbridge  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
    9   582 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker_gwbridge *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   180 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5003 to:172.18.0.2:5003
    1    84 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

In the DOCKER-INGRESS chain, the pkt count increases when I try to access the server from Docker03 instance, but does not increase when I try to access it from the host machine (Host-591).

Inside Docker03:

```
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# ifconfig
...
docker_gwbridge Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:a5:66:fb:c6
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:a5ff:fe66:fbc6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3768 (3.7 KB)  TX bytes:3560 (3.5 KB)

ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:4d:a9:67
          inet addr:192.168.122.103  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe4d:a967/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16582 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7988 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:27505482 (27.5 MB)  TX bytes:773745 (773.7 KB)
...
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# docker service ls
ID            NAME      MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
jgsuip3oda4e  app3_web  replicated  1/1       app3-web:v1

root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# docker service inspect jgsuip3oda4e
[
    {
        "ID": "jgsuip3oda4ef2soefj0ce2oh",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 26
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2018-08-20T16:13:40.627151395Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2018-08-20T16:13:40.628064367Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "app3_web",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "app3"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "app3-web:v1",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "app3"
                    }
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "Placement": {},
                "ForceUpdate": 0
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "Networks": [
                {
                    "Target": "giz5m1weca0xjlcsxjnvm5e81",
                    "Aliases": [
                        "web"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 81,
                        "PublishedPort": 5003,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 81,
                        "PublishedPort": 5003,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 81,
                    "PublishedPort": 5003,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "s067fap1788lt9le1nfc5l2yh",
                    "Addr": "10.255.0.3/16"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkID": "giz5m1weca0xjlcsxjnvm5e81",
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.2/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "UpdateStatus": {
            "StartedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "CompletedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
giz5m1weca0x        app3_webnet         overlay             swarm
a2a6a0d8d2eb        bridge              bridge              local
3d5bf5444e12        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
97d487b3203e        host                host                local
s067fap1788l        ingress             overlay             swarm
efb9d06c92a8        none                null                local
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# docker network inspect docker_gwbridge
[
    {
        "Name": "docker_gwbridge",
        "Id": "3d5bf5444e12adb0d8ed307144de2047372b5f56b2dead9718b414c8e6afa75b",
        "Created": "2018-08-20T12:04:26.440509262-04:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "9eb13ae864ef07243c9b6c89713680248db9ba8e4e914e2f0173923c38d87d6f": {
                "Name": "gateway_9eb13ae864ef",
                "EndpointID": "48e44bfe94366c783f8bc59d1ed1bc3b8cefbbe534cdb4bf7cedfc4852b91213",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ingress-sbox": {
                "Name": "gateway_ingress-sbox",
                "EndpointID": "a9e15a62d6a678b2beb078f2eb99933c48ce44ebf4d2cc2912090ef75a12b75d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "false",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker_gwbridge"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# docker network inspect app3_webnet
[
    {
        "Name": "app3_webnet",
        "Id": "giz5m1weca0xjlcsxjnvm5e81",
        "Created": "2018-08-20T12:13:40.787096192-04:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "9eb13ae864ef07243c9b6c89713680248db9ba8e4e914e2f0173923c38d87d6f": {
                "Name": "app3_web.1.8cejzgd75xul8brdjjjjnq0rb",
                "EndpointID": "b5717c1dff888d993ff9a573b7967f90165c35e35774ca479b5d37cf0821e00d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "app3"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "Docker03-03ead807e067",
                "IP": "192.168.122.103"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the docker compose file that I am using:

```
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
        web:
                image: "app3-web:v1"
                ports:
                        - "5003:81"
                networks:
                        - "webnet"
networks:
        webnet:
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# netstat -tulpn | grep 5003
tcp6       0      0 :::5003                 :::*                    LISTEN      1610/dockerd
```

The Dockerfile for the app looks like this:

```
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# cat web/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /web
WORKDIR /web
RUN pip install --proxy <proxy_ip_address:port> --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 81

# set environment variable so that python does not buffer any output logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 0
CMD ["python", "index.py"]
```

I tried to spin up another VM instance connected to the 192.168.122.0/24 network and access the Flask server, and it worked fine. It seems only access from outside the VMs is not working. Docker version I am using:

```
root@Docker03:/home/ubuntu/docker/app3# docker --version
Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I have a similar issue, but I need to access a container from another network. Did you open (expose) ports in web server? `But from the host linux machine, I am not able to access the server.

[root@Host-591 ~]# curl http://192.168.122.103:81/
^C`
try to telnet port 81 from the host machine

Comment: Check this please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092753/connecting-to-docker-container-from-outside-docker-compose-container