# Connecting to docker container from outside docker-compose container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

### Our two services

We have LXV `virtual-machine-1` where we have docker-compose with `service-1` and other services.
We have another LXV `virtual-machine-2` where we have docker-compose with `service-B` and new other services. Let's assume these two services use ports 80 and 81

### Question

How to connect from `service-1` to `service-B` in separate docker compositions in separate LXV virtual machines.

### What we tried

We changed `hosts` file on LXV `virtual-machine-2` by adding mapping service-1 and ip address of `virtual-machine-1`. `virtual-machine-1` has a forward proxy which is configured and forwards requests to `service-1`

`ping service-1` and `telnet service-1 80` from `virtual-machine-2` work.
However, same ping does not work inside the container in docker-compose of `virtual-machine-2`.

Comment: You shouldn't have to touch ip's or hosts file to connect between containers in the same docker compose network. They will already have an internal dns pointing container names to their ip address. You should just be able to use virtual-machine-2:81

Comment: do you use Overlay as network driver instead of the default bridge connector ? https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: driver: bridge. Docker-compose v2.1

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, docker container has default `hosts` file. So we needed to add a record of `service-B` IP mapping into `hosts` file into `service-1` container `hosts` file.
We modified starting sh script to do so.

Comment: you don't need to use a starting script, if you're using docker-compose. you can use the `extra_hosts` stanza in the docker-compose.yml itself. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts